# What is the "Mean curvature vector" in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: differential-geometry

I need to understand the terminology "Mean curvature vector" in $\mathbb{R}^4$. How can we understand this terminology ? For example, what is "mean curvature vector" of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$, of a 2-dimensional sphere in $\mathbb{R}^4$, 2-dimensional cylinder in a hypersurface?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2197632/472818, though that's about 3D while this is about 4D.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec u\in\mathbb R^2$ be coordinates for a variable point $\vec x\in\mathbb R^4$ on the surface. A basis for the tangent plane at $\vec x$ is given by $\vec e_k=\partial\vec x/\partial u_k$ (for $k=1,2$), which has a corresponding [reciprocal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis) $\vec e^k$ given by

$$\vec e^1=\frac{(\vec e_2\cdot\vec e_2)\vec e_1-(\vec e_1\cdot\vec e_2)\vec e_2}{(\vec e_1\cdot\vec e_1)(\vec e_2\cdot\vec e_2)-(\vec e_1\cdot\vec e_2)^2},$$

$$\vec e^2=\frac{(\vec e_1\cdot\vec e_1)\vec e_2-(\vec e_1\cdot\vec e_2)\vec e_1}{(\vec e_1\cdot\vec e_1)(\vec e_2\cdot\vec e_2)-(\vec e_1\cdot\vec e_2)^2}.$$

(Verify that $\vec e^k\cdot\vec e_l=\delta^k_l$.) Define the projection $P_\parallel$ onto the tangent plane, $\vec v\mapsto P_\parallel(\vec v)=\sum_k(\vec v\cdot\vec e^k)\vec e_k$, and the rejection $P_\perp$ from the tangent plane, $\vec v\mapsto P_\perp(\vec v)=\vec v-P_\parallel(\vec v)$. Then one possible definition of the mean curvature vector is

$$2\vec H=\sum_{k,l}\left(\vec e^k\cdot\vec e^l\right)P_\perp\left(\frac{\partial\vec e_k}{\partial u_l}\right)=\sum_{k,l}\left(\vec e^k\cdot\vec e^l\right)P_\perp\left(\frac{\partial\partial\vec x}{\partial u_l\partial u_k}\right).$$

It can be shown that this is independent of the choice of coordinates. The factor of $2$, or the dimension of the manifold, may or may not be included as a matter of convention.

---

The mean curvature vector, or any type of curvature, of a plane is $0$.

For a 2D sphere with radius $a$ and centre $0$ in 4D, one parametrization is

$$\vec x=(a\cos u_1\cos u_2,\;a\sin u_1\cos u_2,\;a\sin u_2,\;0)=a\,\hat x$$

(the hat indicating a unit vector). I won't go through the calculations; the result is

$$2\vec H=-\frac2a\hat x.$$

Comment: Excuse me, the mean curvature vector in above is "vector H" or "vector 2H" ?

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm studying surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$, there are many different things in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Can you give me a parametrization of a cylinder in $\mathbb{R}^4$ ?

Comment: An ordinary 2D cylinder in 4D has just the same form as in 3D, but with $0$ as the fourth coordinate: $$\vec x=(a\cos u_1,\;a\sin u_1,\;u_2,\;0).$$ Or, more generally, $$\vec x=\vec a\cos u_1+\vec b\sin u_1+\vec cu_2+\vec d$$ where $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c,\vec d$ are constants; $\vec c$ represents the direction of the cylinder's axis, and $\vec d$ is some point on the axis. And you can make a 3D "hypercylinder" or "spherinder" by taking a parametrization of a sphere and adding $(0,0,0,u_3)$ or something like that.

Comment: Do you know about partial derivatives? sigma notation? vector dot products? These are essential to understanding my answer.

Comment: That's probably why someone downvoted your question: You should give some context to show how much you know, and what concepts should be used in an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I am reading an other different approach to mean curvature vector $\overrightarrow{H}$. That is $\overrightarrow{H}$ = H.$\overrightarrow{N}$, where N is vectors in normal space to the surface S, H is mean curvature( scalar). And I just want to compute $\overrightarrow{H}$ in some simple cases such as planes, 2-spheres, 2-cylinders in above.

Comment: Can you explain more details of geometric meaning of mean curvature vector? For example in the case planes, spheres?

Comment: First consider the curvature vector of a curve: It's the acceleration with respect to arclength, $d^2\vec x/ds^2$, or equivalently the curvature scalar times the normal vector, $\kappa\hat N$. (But in 3D or higher there's not a unique normal vector, so $\kappa\hat N$ is not a good definition.) Then the mean curvature vector of a surface is just the sum (or average) of curvature vectors of two curves, perpendicular to each other, passing through the point on the surface. Actually the two curves should be geodesics, meaning their curvature vectors are orthogonal to the surface.